# JQuery Accordion: Resizing My Header Control

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, accordion

I am using the JQuery Accordion. All is well in FireFox. In IE7, however, when I click a link in my document that expands one of the accordion menu headings my header server control is re sized (shrunken). How do I stop the screen re sizing? This is the peice of JavaScript in question:

```
if (!$('h3.ReferenceBackgroundHeader', '#References').hasClass('ui-state-active')) {

                $("#References").accordion('activate', 0);

            }

            window.scrollTo(0, $('#References').offset().top);
            return false;
```

---

What I want is the `.accordion('activate',indexval);` to not change my header formatting.

---

Weird.. There has to be a work around for this in IE. If I empty my function out and just run:

```
window.scroll(0,900);
```

I still loose my sever control at top?! Anyone have a suggestion?

---

Perhaps this is the problem.. The page is actually made up of two divs. The top div is for displaying the header control (before the days of MasterPages) and the bottom section is the section I am attempting to scroll within. The "content" div is the one I require the ability to scroll. The "header" div is the one that disappears when I scroll. Can anyone save me yet? :)

```
<body>
<form id="Form1" method="post" runat="server">
    <div id="header">
        <uc1:Header ID="headerControl" runat="server"></uc1:Header>
    </div>
    <div id="content" style="overflow:auto">
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="contentPlaceholder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got it figured out. I am working on legacy code that I inherited. I was barking up the wrong tree. I found the following code in the header of the page giving me grief:

```
function resizeContentWindowScrollBar() {
         var contentDiv = document.getElementById("content");
         var header = document.getElementById("header");

         if (header != null) {
             var desiredHeight = document.body.clientHeight - header.clientHeight;

             if (desiredHeight > 0) {
                 contentDiv.style.height = (document.body.clientHeight - header.clientHeight) + "px";

             }
         }


     }
```

Notice the header.clientHeight calls? This snippet obviously just gets the header height and with this equates the content div height. The problem was (and only in IE mind you) the clientHeight function was always returning "0". I replaced these with header.offsetHeight and all is well.

So it would appear that in IE my clientHeight functions where not working correctly.

Comment: Nice, glad you figured out the problem. You should select this "answer" as the correct one so people know it is solved.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a scrollbar in your browser before and after you expand the menu?

What might be happening is that before you expand the menu, everything fits on the screen, so the browser doesn't give you a scrollbar; but when you expand the menu it needs more space, so the browser adds a scrollbar, causing the webpage to "scale" down.

I'm not sure how to fix that issue without setting a large `min-height` in your css file so that the scrollbar always shows up.

Hope that helps.

***UPDATE:*** I just found [a website](http://ryanfait.com/resources/forcing-vertical-scrollbars/) which talks about how to fix the scrollbar issue. Just wanted to let anyone else who comes across this a much cleaner fix.

Comment: I think you are right.. I will experiment with this some more but this sounds very likely.